# How to count total patch sets in gerrit?

Tags: patch, gerrit

Within Gerrit, how can I determine the number of patch sets for all of the patches on a given project?

We're currently reviewing our code review process, and we'd like to be able to identify the average number of patch sets for any given patch.  Ideally, we'd like to be able to generate a distribution showing the range of sets per patch.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this information accessing the Gerrit database. The following example is using a MySQL database (change accordingly).

1. Connect to the Gerrit database

`mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 --database=gerrit --user=gerrit --password`

2. List all patchsets from the "sandbox/helloworld" project

`SELECT pat.change_id, pat.patch_set_id FROM patch_sets pat INNER JOIN changes cha on cha.change_id = pat.change_id WHERE cha.dest_project_name = 'sandbox/helloworld';`

3. Count the number of patchsets of the "sandbox/helloworld" project

`SELECT count(*) FROM patch_sets pat INNER JOIN changes cha on cha.change_id = pat.change_id WHERE cha.dest_project_name = 'sandbox/helloworld';`